# Auto convert LaTeX escape codes to UTF-8 characters?

Tags: unicode, emacs, auctex, characters, input-encodings

How do I—e.g., with AucTeX—automatically convert escaped characters like `\~n` to `ñ` for use with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`?

I could do something like this:

```
sed         \
 -e "s/\\'a/á/"     \
 -e "s/\\'e/é/"     \
 -e "s/\\'i/í/"     \
 -e "s/\\'o/ó/"     \
 -e "s/\\'u/ú/"     \
 -e "s/\\'A/Á/"     \
 -e "s/\\'E/É/"     \
 -e "s/\\'I/Í/"     \
 -e "s/\\'O/Ó/"     \
 -e "s/\\'U/Ú/"     \
 -e "s/\\'{\\a}/á/" \
 -e "s/\\'{\\e}/é/" \
 -e "s/\\'{\\i}/í/" \
 -e "s/\\'{\\o}/ó/" \
 -e "s/\\'{\\u}/ú/" \
 -e "s/\\'{\\A}/Á/" \
 -e "s/\\'{\\E}/É/" \
 -e "s/\\'{\\I}/Í/" \
 -e "s/\\'{\\O}/Ó/" \
 -e "s/\\'{\\U}/Ú/" filename.tex > out.tex
```

But unfortunately out.tex isn't UTF-8 and the special characters are replaced by codes in Emacs.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Doesn't `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` handle that, though?

Comment: I will take your word on it, and delete my earlier comment... `inputenc` is not my strong suit.

Comment: Do you mean replace-as-you-type or just 'fix' existing files?  For the second, it is more of an Emacs question (or could be done by external tools)...

Comment: @jon either. I've also added an emacs tag to the question.

Comment: It's not UTF-8?  It is for me.  (I guess: what encoding does your terminal use?)  But, anyway, you could run that through `iconv` as a final step on the way to `out.tex`.

Comment: Add `% -*- coding: utf-8; -*-` as first line of your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs has the commands `iso-iso2tex` and `iso-tex2iso` that work very well, except it doesn't convert single commands like `\OE` to `Œ`.

Comment: I think you can add the `\\\\OE` entry to the `iso-tex2iso-trans-tab` variable.